# Sort by name in Select2

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2

Is there any way to sort my list generated by select2 by name? I have some code :

```
var dataUser = [{
    "id": "5",
    "text": "BTest"
}, {
    "id": "2",
    "text": "ATest"
}, {
    "id": "8",
    "text": "CTest"
}, {
    "id": "13",
    "text": "DTest"
}];


$("#mylist").select2({
    data: dataUser,
    templateResult: function(data) {
        return data.text;
    },
    sorter: function(data) {    
        return data.sort();
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/oe9retsL/4/

This list sorts by id, but I want sort by text.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to provide a function to `sort()` which contains the logic to compare the `text` property of each object in the array. Try this:

```
sorter: data => data.sort((a, b) => a.text < b.text ? -1 : a.text > b.text ? 1 : 0);

// legacy version, for IE support:
sorter: function(data) {
    return data.sort(function(a, b) {
        return a.text < b.text ? -1 : a.text > b.text ? 1 : 0;
    });
}
```

To sort the selected options you need to implement similar logic on the tag well when an option is selected, like this:

```js
const dataUser = [{ "id": "5", "text": "BTest" }, { "id": "2", "text": "ATest" }, { "id": "8", "text": "CTest" }, { "id": "13", "text": "DTest" }];
const sortHandler = (a, b) => $(a).text() < $(b).text() ? -1 : $(a).text() > $(b).text() ? 1 : 0;

$("#mylist").select2({
  data: dataUser,
  templateResult: data => data.text,
  sorter: data => data.sort(sortHandler)
}).on("select2:select", () => {
  $('.select2-selection__rendered li.select2-selection__choice').sort(sortHandler).prependTo('.select2-selection__rendered');
});
```

```css
select {
  width: 140px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.1/js/select2.full.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.1/css/select2.min.css" />
<select name="list" id="mylist" multiple></select>
```

Comment: Yeah, works perfect, but is there any way to sort already selected options?

Comment: Wow, great and fast solution! :) Thank You @Rory McCrossan !

Comment: No problem, glad to help.

Comment: Ok @Rory McCrossan I have one mistake. When I add the second field select2 that such miracles happen: http://jsfiddle.net/oe9retsL/7/

Comment: Here you go: http://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/oe9retsL/8/. You need to use the `this` reference in the handler to find the tag well related to the `select`.

Comment: I'm immensely grateful to You!

Comment: I found one error in this sort @Rory McCrossan. You can remove sensitive detection? See what happens when I add a lowercase 'a'. http://jsfiddle.net/oe9retsL/10/ This value is given at the end of the list

Comment: You need to convert both values to the same case to remove the case-sensitivity: http://jsfiddle.net/oe9retsL/11/

Comment: Very fast! :) And what if when We have such a space before signs. It is possible to handle this?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by 'space before signs'. If you have issues with the code it's probably best to open a new question.