# Select2 jQuery Plugin: sort the list after creating a new tag

Tags: javascript, jquery-select2

I want to sort the list by name whenever a new tag is created, is that achievable? the sorter option does not sort the created tag also on select2 events

```
$tag_select.select2({
   tags: true,
   allowClear: true,
   placeholder: "No tag",
   createTag: function (params) {
      let term = $.trim(params.term);
      if (term === '') {
         return null;
      }
      return {
          id: term,
          text: term,
          newTag: true // add additional parameters
      }
   },
   insertTag: function (data, tag, sample) {
      data.unshift(tag);
   },
   sorter: data => data.sort((a, b) => a.text.localeCompare(b.text))
});
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sort by name in Select2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34788259/sort-by-name-in-select2)

Comment: Nah @RifatBinReza what I want is create a new tag, select again the selection it should sort the list in the select

Comment: You wanna sort the selected tags or dropdown list?

Comment: If your data source is from options under select in html, your sort won't work like this. If your data is from json, then it will work. I'm not sure yet why that's the case

Comment: @RifatBinReza sort the dropdown list with the new tag

Comment: @RifatBinReza the snippet is empty

Comment: Sorry, the link is this one https://jsfiddle.net/v8gn7deb/1/

Comment: @RifatBinReza I get what you mean i may have a solution now. instead of listing the option in HTML it should be in select2 data so the sorter will take effect. Thanks

Comment: Yeah that's the easy solution. I think there's a better way to do it even with options from HTML.

Comment: Will that be achievable?